# Gstreamer input into opencv

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, gstreamer

From this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41398886/capture-stream-from-raspberrry-pi-using-gstreamer-in-opencv) I think I may be close but I don't get any errors except for the Nonetype errors when I use the stream.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("tcpclientsrc host=192.168.1.111 port=5000  ! gdpdepay !  rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! opencvsink sync=false")
```

I am struggling to find the mistake in the above line. Has anyone accomplished this and mind helping me out.

I have a raspberry pi posting a video stream with gstreamer and can successfully stream it onto an Ubuntu pc with gstreamer in terminal.

Sender:

```
raspivid -t 999999 -h 720 -w 1080 -fps 25 -hf -b 2000000 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! h264parse !  rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=192.168.1.111 port=5000
```

Reciever

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v tcpclientsrc host=192.168.1.111 port=5000  ! gdpdepay !  rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false
```

The python script I am trying to get working

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('tcpclientsrc host=192.168.1.111 port=5000  ! gdpdepay !  rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! '
                           'videoconvert ! appsink')

while True:
    r, frame = cap.read()

    try:
        cv2.imshow('yes', frame)
    except cv2.error as e:
        print(e)
```

Gives the error `OpenCV(3.4.3) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:356: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'`

Comment: What is the question? Please post the error messages!

Comment: sorry, I added the code and error. @micha137

Answer (score 2):

This posting conversation along with many others helped me formulate a solution. I managed to stream video wirelessly from Raspberry Pi 4 Model B to Jetson Nano with GStreamer and OpenCV using the following:

**Launching GStreamer on Raspberry Pi:**

```
raspivid -t 0 -h 720 -w 1080 -fps 25 -hf b 2000000 -o – | gstlaunch-1.0 v fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! config-interval=1 pt=96 ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=192.168.1.147 port=5000
```

**Receiving video stream in Jetson Nano terminal:**

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v tcpclientsrc host=192.168.1.147 port=5000 ! gdpdepay ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false
```

**Receiving video stream in Jetson Nano VideoCapture object:**

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

RaspiStreamCam=cv2.VideoCapture(‘tcpclientsrc host=192.168.1.147 port=5000 ! gdpdepay ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw, format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! appsink’, cv2.CAP_STREAMER)

while True:

    ret, frameRaspiIP=RaspiStreamCam.read()

    cv2.imshow(‘RaspiStreamCam’,frameRaspiIP)

    if cv2.waitKey(1)==ord(‘q’):
        break

RaspiStreamCam.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `appsink` instead of `opencvsink`?

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("tcpclientsrc host=192.168.1.111 port=5000  ! gdpdepay !  rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! appsink")
```

Comment: It didn't work and I can't give feedback because the error only comes on the imshow() line.

Comment: could you try checking `r` before `imshow`? `if r is True:  cv2.imshow('yes', frame)`

Answer (score 0):

To get log messages from gstreamer, [set GST_DEBUG](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gst-running.html) before running your Python script.  E.g.:

```
GST_DEBUG=4 ./script.py
```